# Is buying train and bus tickets from a third-party website sensible?

Tags: tickets, europe, planning

I checked omio website for bus and train ticket. Does anybody know whether it is trustable and we can easily buy tickets?

[image: screenshot of train schedule and map]

Are these times Ok?

Is it risky to buy ticket in person when I want to leave? I mean, could we find an empty bus if we wait to buy in person?

Comment: Which country is this?

Comment: All around the europe!

Comment: A website that claims that a train from Zürich to Basel is operated by Deutsche Bahn  is not one that I would trust….

Comment: it is not zurich to basel! It is zurich to hamburg with a transfer in basel

Comment: You can search in german website also you will see that!

Comment: Also , it is not written that Bahn operates the train

Comment: @KristvanBesien DB operates trains on the Zürich to Basel track segment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercity_Express#Line_segments_abroad

Comment: @AhmadTurani The trains between Zurich and Basel are usually operated by SBB, not bei Deutsche Bahn. The exception are ICEs (but even then "normal" swiss tickets are valid), for those you don't have to change trains in Basel. (www.sbb.ch gives a direct connection departing Zurich at 13:59 and arriving in Hamburg Hbf ad 22:29)

Comment: @nohillside  so if I buy from that website then there will be no problem right?regardless of which train operates and etc.? Specifically the one with transfer I mean. You are right but I think that website offers cost-effective one. I am not sure

Comment: https://www.omio.com/search-frontend/results/EBD675B6B5C3042BDAEB97B7E2FFC91F4/train?locale=en&abTestParameters=&arrival_fk=376583&departure_date=12/07/2021&departure_fk=373297&passengerages%5B0%5D=26:57:&request_partner_id=&spa=&travel_mode=bus&user_currency=EUR&user_domain=com&user_id=0.bwfcbk4cn8p25anfsj71hbbj4i&user_locale=en could you please check this and the one you mentioned? The price difference is too much!

Comment: I looked at DB it also offers zurich hamburg with better price. It was IC i think

Comment: @AhmadTurani If DB is cheaper, go for it (I have no experience with Omio). One hint: take direct connections if possible, each transfer increases the risk of missing a connecting train due to delays.

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk DB does not operate any trains between Basel and Zürich. When the ICE runs in Switzerland it is operated by SBB, with SBB drivers and crew, as an SBB service. Same when ICE runs in Austria (where it is an Austrian train) or with RJ outside of Austria. It is not because there is a particular logo on a train that the train is operated by that company… There are even DB ICE sets used on pure Swiss domestic services…

Comment: Generally speaking for Switzerland - Germany trains the best wegsite to book is www.bahn.de. And don’t worry about transfers, or who runs your train. This is mass transit,  not air travel. A ticket Zürich- Hamburg entitles you to travel that route, and you will eventually get there. If you miss a connection because a train ran late you just take the next one…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to look up train times for trips in Europe is the German Railways’ website: http://www.bahn.de
There you will find basically all trains, and for trips to/from/through Germany you can also buy tickets.
For the example given here, Zürich to Hamburg this would be the best option.

This site will also tell you who operates a train, so that for trains that Deutsche Bahn does not sell tickets for you can go to the operator’s site.

Alternatively just head to the website of the national railway of the country where your trip starts.

Sites like omio and rome2rio will often find suboptimal routes.

Comment: thank you, by the way it is not just train. some options are also for bus,

Comment: In Germany it also does local buses, not sure about long distance buses.

Answer (score 4):

> Does anybody know whether it is trustable

They seem to have partnered with Rome2Rio which is a reputable and frequently used website.

For test purposes, I put it in a trip that I just travelled yesterday and it found good but not the best options.

> and we can easily buy tickets?

Probably yes, but I personally always buy the ticket directly from the provider. My recommendation is to use this website to find the best (or good) option and then book and research the provider directly.

> Is it risky to buy ticket in person while going to destination?

It's not risky as in "dangerous". There are downsides: buying in person you typically pay more then buying online or upfront. The bus can be full and there may be no seats left. Payment can be tricky: You may not have the right denomination/change for counter or the ticket machine. Lines at a counter can be long and so you miss your bus.

> I mean in this season could we find an empty bus if we wait to buy in person/?

Unlikely. If you want to get a feel how empty a bus is you can try to track seat availability through online booking tools (at least for some busses). However, things change quickly. Your best shot is to book early and reserve the seat you want.

Comment: Thank you. So we use this website and it shows different providers and we can go to their website directly and buy that ticket? for example blablabus and etc.?

Comment: Also, there are some transfers between, for some options. Does this mean we just need to wait at the stop without changing the station? For example, https://www.omio.com/search-frontend/results/E01667A4DD82440A795A0C6920703CE41/train?locale=en&abTestParameters=&arrival_fk=376583&departure_date=23/08/2021&departure_fk=373297&passengerages%5B0%5D=26:57:&request_partner_id=&spa=&travel_mode=bus&user_currency=EUR&user_domain=com&user_id=0.bwfcbk4cn8p25anfsj71hbbj4i&user_locale=en. The 30 euro option. I added a photo to my post

Comment: In your picture it is the same station, although you might need to change platforms, since this station has multiple platforms.. You might get transfers in the result, where you need to change stations, but that should be marked in the results as well then.

Comment: I also checked here (https://shop.global.flixbus.com/search?departureCity=40d8fa3c-8646-11e6-9066-549f350fcb0c&arrivalCity=40d91e53-8646-11e6-9066-549f350fcb0c&route=Zurich-Hamburg&rideDate=14.08.2021&adult=1&_locale=en&features%5Bfeature.darken_page%5D=1&features%5Bfeature.enable_distribusion%5D=1&_uc=cfbad6099a8f1018351cb3b3e11ac0a852dcfe6c4d61bd7514e108cfd806d70e#) The flexibus. It is matched with omio exactly. for example 30 euro option

Comment: Another thing, I want to ask is one of the users' answer above regarding the zurich hamburg train. So, isn't it not possible that "Zürich to Basel is operated by Deutsche Bahn". is it like that?!!

Comment: Please all of you, remember our first rule, "be nice".